# How to construct rdf4j Model from oslc4j Domains using rdf4j?

Tags: rdf, jena, rdf4j, oslc

I constructed org.eclipse.lyo.oslc.domains.qm.TestCase and want to transform it into rdf4j Model.
Is there a way using rdf4j library?
It should be equivalent to JenaModelHelper.createJenaModel(objects);

Comment: Unsubtle way - make Jena model, print to string, parse string with RDF4J.
Or
RDFCommons. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-rdf/

Comment: Thanks for your help, I thought there is direct way without converting.

Comment: CommonsRDF should be quite cheap - the conversion of object isn't very complex.

Comment: @AbdelrahmanElattar if you're keen on getting this supported directly, do please log a feature request with the lyo / oslc4j project.